# Petition for not closing any single question here on Islam.SE

Tags: discussion

I am staring this thread inspired by comment of Dan Andrews on this question [How do we make sure that we are on the rightful religion/path?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2278/how-do-we-make-sure-that-we-are-on-the-rightful-religion-path) 
He said that " They will probably close it".
Looks like our colleagues at Judaism.SE already have reputation of fast closing community.

The most of answers here came from Muslims so Ill try to say few facts how Do I understand Islam to help others to be more tolerant.

Once during time of Muhamed (peace been upon him) one of Bedouin start to urinating inside the mosque. Ahbab of the Prophet start jelling him. In the meantime Muhamed said leave him alone to finish what he has started, if we start attack him now it will be urea allover mosque When He finish sprinkle water on site and tell him that we that do not do that inside mosque.

Today there is a lot question which came here that looks worst than urinating inside mosque.
Like this one :

> Mufakhathat(thighing) is the placing of the male member between the
>   thighs of a female for sexual gratification. There are conflicting
>   views on this practice with some saying it is permitted between a
>   husband and their wife, others say it is also permitted between an
>   adult male and a female infan...

My opinion is that We should not delete this question, We should try explain that Islam is 
clear and natural and to We do not allow something like that in Islam.

Another references is when Muahamed (PBUH) was stoned by some
    children, He prayed to forgive them because they do not know yet
    well. He did not cursed them nor ask Allah to punish them.

My Imam always repeating :

> > ["So by mercy from Allah , [O Muhammad], you were lenient with them. And if you had been rude [in speech] and harsh in heart, they would have disbanded from about you. So pardon them and ask forgiveness for them and consult them in the matter. And when you have decided, then rely upon Allah . Indeed, Allah loves those who rely [upon Him]..](http://quran.com/3/159)

Can we considered this site as something universal for all kind of question, Because Islam is not hobby or profession, It is something whit which you living and Islam looking and examines all aspects of life.

Comment: Just for clarification, the thighing question was not removed by the community; it was deleted of the owner's own accord.

Comment: I don't think `We do not alow something like that in Islam.` is a correct statement. It is not us who allow or disallow things in Islam. We submit to whatever is commanded upon us.

Comment: I think this is the ayah you are talking about: http://quran.com/3/159

Answer (score 7):

I would like to make something very clear to you, **questions on this website are not closed due to religious disagreement with the facts presented**

sometimes, it's required to close a question, based on the categories below, if we want to build a long lasting, expert website, we have to follow the same rules websites with higher reputation that us do.We don't want this website to end up like an Islamic forum, un-moderated and without boundaries.

the choices to close question are:

- exact duplicate This question covers exactly the same content as
  earlier questions on this topic; its answers may be merged with
  another identical question
- off topic Questions on Islam - Stack Exchange are expected to relate
  to Islam within the scope defined in the FAQ. Consider editing the
  question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the
  question can be reworded to fit within the scope.
- not constructive As it currently stands, this question is not a good
  fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts,
  references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely
  solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you
  feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see
  the FAQ for guidance.
- not a real question It's difficult to tell what is being asked here.
  This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or
  rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For
  help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the
  FAQ.
- too localized This question is unlikely to help any future visitors;
  it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in
  time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally
  applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making
  this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ

there is no choice to close a question because you don't agree, in fact its the opposite, when you don't agree with a question you strive to disprove the questionnaire.

For example, the question you quoted above, asked if thighing was allowed in islam. Of course some may have been deeply disturbed with information presented, ***but there wasn't a single close vote.*** instead there was discussion in the chat room with ways to answer the question, we asked the questionnaire where they found that quote, and the questionnaire himself said  after further evaluation, they found that the source wasn't reliable information, and deleted the question on their own accord, as pointed out earlier.

and of course if you still don't agree with questions that are being closed there is the [review page](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/) so you can vote whether to close the question or not.

Comment: Good answer, but in off-topic point, you wrote the rules according to meta site instead of main site.

Comment: oops i copied and pasted by suggesting to close this answer- fixed.